# javascript - attr('href') not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, href

I have a script on my site that doesn't appear to be working in IE8.

The aim is to click the link in Section 2 (below) and retrieve the href in Section 1 and pass into the countries.loadajaxpage script.

Section 1

```
<a id="circle_all_all" class="circle selected" href="my_news_all_al.php" rel="popularcontainer" style="display:block;"></a>
```

Section 2

```
<a onclick="var circle = $('.selected a').attr('href');var c = circle.slice(0, -7);countries.loadajaxpage(c+'_al.php');>Click here</a>
```

I have tried using alert(circles) to see if it works in IE8 and it doesn't (works in other browsers, including IE9)

You help will be highly appreaciated.

Thank you all in advance.

George

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var circle = $('a.selected')
```